# Devise Layouts for SignedIn & Signed Out resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My App has two UI states:
 - Signed IN
 - Signed Out

I've been using the following to determine which app/view/layout to use based on if the user is signed in or out with Devise:

```
  # Devise, way of using a different Layout for all the devise/non-signed in Views
  layout :layout_by_resource
  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "application_unauthorized"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
```

The problem is once your signed in it uses the wrong layout? ideas?

I only want to use "application_unauthorized" if it's devise & the user is not signed in.

Comment: Please provide more context with your questions. I have found them to be lacking in it :(

Comment: @ryan, sorry about that, just updated. Better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you should use the `user_signed_in?` method to check if the user is signed in. I noticed that `current_user?` might return `true` even if the user is currently not signed in.

So your code would look something like this:

```
layout :layout_by_resource
def layout_by_resource
  if user_signed_in?
    "application"
  else
    "application_unauthorized"
  end
end
```

Comment: Quick question, where do you put that code? In the application controller?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would check using `if current_user?` rather than `devise_controller?`

Comment: Agreed. The test `devise_controller?` tests whether you are inside a devise controller, not even whether there is a current user signed in. Ryan's answer is correct imho.